# how to download blobs using azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm using data factory to create my pipeline, and I'm facing some challenges.
the pipeline consists of a lookup which has a json array and a foreach to loop this json array and finally a set variable inside the foreach loop:

pipeline :

[image]

lookup :

[image]

variable :

[image]

now what I'm looking for is to pass the result of the set variable value(which is a like to an image) to a copy activity or something like that in order to doawnload the image in our datalake container.
and the name of doownloaded image should be like this :

> id +'_'+guid()+'.png'

thanks for your help

Comment: You can't pass the results, but you can use the URL as the Source in a COPY activity (with an HTTP DataSet) and your Data Lake as the Sink. The sink will permit you to specify the name.

Comment: thanks for you reply, I'm trying to use the copy acivity but it give this error :ErrorCode=UserErrorInvalidHttpUrlAddress,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Http Url Address 'https://www.url.com/productimages/sku/s1200716-main-zoom.jpg?imwidth=48' is invalid.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'

Comment: Can you share more information about your Http dataset? Is it Binary? It looks like an issue with the URL, so check the BaseUrl settings and the relative path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `copy data` activity and connecting source dataset to **HTTP** connector to execute the URL and sink to data lake storage, you can copy the images to data lake as shown below.

1. Using the `lookup` activity, get the array value from the JSON file.

**Output of lookup:**

[image]

2. Passing the output of the `lookup` activity to `Foreach` activity.

`@activity('Lookup1').output.value`

[image]

3. Inside `Foreach` activity, use `copy data` activity to copy the image from URL to data lake.

> Using a `set variable` is optional to store the URL from lookup output as you can directly use the current item in copy activity.

**Source dataset:**

- Create **HttpServer** linked service by parameterizing the URL and with the **binary** dataset.

[image]

- In the source dataset, pass the dataset parameter to the linked service parameter value.

[image]

4. In **source** settings, pass the current item URLs column to the dataset property **item().urls**.

[image]

5. Connect the **sink** to data lake storage with binary dataset and create a dataset parameter to provide the name of the file in the sink dataset.

[image]

6. In **sink** settings, provide the dataset file name as required.

`@concat(item().id,'_',guid(),'.png')`

[image]

Sink file in data lake:

**Image1:**

[image]

**Image2:**

[image]